# Woocommerce: change user role after completing order

Tags: plugins, user-roles

:)

I'm using wordpress with woocommerce, and I would like to automate the following step. When an order is completed, I would like to change the user role associated with that order id from 'customer' to 'subscriber'.

By searching around, I think I should be able to accomplish this by using a hook in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_role_from_customer_to_subscriber' );
```

Then add the function:

```
function change_role_from_customer_to_subscriber($order_id){
// code to change role to subscriber
}
```

In the code, I think I need to do 2 things:
1) get the user id that is associated with that order id
2) change role of that user id to subscriber

I've tried a lot, but I couldn't get it to work (neither getting the right user id, nor changing the role of a user id). So any help would be appreciated! I've seen 2 related questions asked before on stack overflow, but unfortunately the answers there did not work for me. I hope someone can help me out!

Thanks a lot! :)

Edit:
Someone helped me out with the second part of the problem, so that's great news for me :)

Unfortunately, I still haven't figured out the first part: how to get the user id that is associated with the order id.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you include something of what you tried so far to give us a starting point? Maybe you almost did it and there's only a small piece missing or wrong...

Comment: Great idea! First thing I tried:
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'myemailaddress' );
$u = new WP_User( $user );
$u->remove_role( 'customer' );
$u->add_role( 'subscriber' );

Comment: Second thing I tried: $user = get_user_by_email( 'myemailaddress' ); $u= new WP_User($user); $u->set_role('subscriber');

Comment: Edit your question to post the code, it is really hard to read code in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the code there is a very relevant example:

```
function woocommerce_paying_customer( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {

        $old_spent = absint( get_user_meta( $order->user_id, '_money_spent', true ) );
        update_user_meta( $order->user_id, '_money_spent', $old_spent + $order->order_total );

        $old_count = absint( get_user_meta( $order->user_id, '_order_count', true ) );
        update_user_meta( $order->user_id, '_order_count', $old_count + 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'woocommerce_paying_customer' );
```

which reminds us that the $order_is passed to the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook. From the $order_id, you can create a new order object, with the user_id as a property.

Armed with that knowledge, I think we can just fix the inner guts of the function get a new user object from that user ID, and remove the old role and finally apply the new role.

```
function wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {
        update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );
        $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer' );
```

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately, it's not working. I'm new to PHP (and coding in general), any ideas on how to debug the code and see where things go wrong?

Comment: Bummer. I have to admit that I didn't test it, but it seemed like a reasonable approach. There are probably better ways to debug, but I'd step through with a `die('some info');` after every line... printing out the variables to see where it is failing.

Comment: The strangest thing just happened: I was reading through my error logs, and tried your script again... and now it worked! Thank you so much, I'm very happy :)

Comment: Well cool! I removed the line about updating the user meta since Woo is handling that and I just forgot to delete it when copying their function.