# Change user role if it's orders count more than

Tags: hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

According this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120656/woocommerce-change-user-role-after-completing-order) i want to count orders of each user, and if count > 3 for example, change role to another.

After searching i found this [hook](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_customer_order_count/)

I have modified function

```
function wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $int = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id );

    if ( $int->user_id > 2 ) {
        update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );
        $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'dovclient' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer' );
```

But it doesn't work...
Help me to find a mistake, please!

Comment: You want to do it for all your current customers that had already orders > 3 or from now, on every time a customer pass the threshold of 3 orders  change the role?

Comment: @Laxmana Now my site is testing, and i think the 2 variant pass for me. This function catch new order, catch user id, if user id has 3 or more orders, change status.

Comment: Ok and why isn't working? What is the problem? Have you test if the action is being fired?

Comment: @Laxmana This function doesn't work, i don't know why...may be $int = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id ); call not right....

Comment: First of all you have to see if the function is being executed, meaning that wordpress is calling the function. You can do this by echo/print_r/error_log inside the function. Secondly check the content of the $int variable by var_dump or print_r

Comment: Are you sure your `$user_id` returns anything? If not, try using `$user_id = $order->user_id;` after the second line of your code, and before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all people that help me to find an answer (0 helpers)!
I found a solution on my own.

```
function wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $user_id = $order->user_id;

    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
    ) );

    if ( $customer_orders > 1 ) {
        update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );
        $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'dovclient' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer' );
```